# Elasticsearch match all tags within given array

Tags: json, node.js, search, elasticsearch

Currently developing a tag search application using elasticsearch, I have given each document within the index an array of tags, here's an example of how a document looks:

```
_source: {
  title: "Keep in touch scheme",
  intro: "<p>hello this is a test</p> ",
  full: " <p>again this is a test mate</p>",
  media: "",
  link: "/training/keep-in-touch",
  tags: [
    "employee",
    "training"
  ]
}
```

I would like to be able to make a search and only return documents with all of the specified tags.

Using the above example, if I searched for a document with tags `["employee", "training"]` then the above result would be returned.

In contrast, if I searched with tags `["employee", "other"]`, then nothing would be returned; all tags within the search query must match.

Currently I am doing:

```
query: {
  bool: {
    must: [
      { match: { tags: ["employee","training"] }}
     ]
   }
 }
```

but I am just getting returned exceptions like

```
IllegalStateException[Can't get text on a START_ARRAY at 1:128];
```

I have also tried concatenating the arrays and using comma-delimited strings, however this seems to match anything given the first tag matches.

Any suggestions on how to approach this? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** Next example should work (v2.3.2):

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/yourIndex/yourType/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "term": { "tags": "employee" } } ,
        { "term": { "tags": "training" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

**Option 2:** Also you can try:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/yourIndex/yourType/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {"match_all": {}},
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "tags": ["employee", "training"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

But without `"minimum_should_match": 1` it works little bin not accurate.
I also found `"execution": "and"` but it works not accurate too.

**Option 3:** Also you cat try `query_string` it works perfectly, but looks little bit complicated:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/yourIndex/yourType/_search?pretty' -d '{
"query" : {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(tags:employee AND tags:training)"
    }
  }
}'
```

Maybe it will be helpful for you...

Comment: the issue with this is the amount of tags could vary, it isn't always 2 - Ideally I could pass an array of varying length to the query

Comment: @WilliamPaul I've added another example, but i can't find solution how to use `"minimum_should_match": 1` in es v2.3.2...

Comment: @WilliamPaul I've also added example with `query_string`.

Comment: option 3 works the best for me, just had to concatenate the array and use some delimiters, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the set contains only the specified values, maintain a secondary field to keep track of the tags count. Then you can query like below to get the desired results

```
"query":{
   "bool":{
        "must":[
             {"term": {"tags": "employee"}},
             {"term": {"tags": "training"}},
             {"term": {"tag_count": 2}}
        ]  
   }
}
```